# How to use onunload or onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, html

All I am looking for is a simple example of the onunload or onbeforeunload functions and how they work. I am mostly looking for where it is located in the html code and how to reference the javascript for it. This doesn't seem like too hard of a task, but I have yet to find anything on the internet that can demonstrate this.

Comment: [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload), [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would simply go in your body tag like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function myBeforeUnloadFunction() {
          return "Write something here";
     }
     function myUnloadFunction() {
           alert("Bye"); //onunload doesn't work the same in all browsers
     }
</script>
<body onunload="myUnloadFunction()" onbeforeunload="return myBeforeUnloadFunction()">
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Am I limited to just that script though or can I perform other functions that wouldn't affect the user? i.e. saving input text that wasn't saved by the user

Comment: Like maybe before the return statment?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I use `beforeunload` to reset the browser's scroll position. I wouldn't apply it inline — it's better to separate your view from your logic. If it's a website or a small application, I put all my events at the bottom of the file, and then I have an application `Object` with methods that help me keep everything organized and idiomatic.

```
var foo = function(){};
    var app = {
      ready: function (){
           foo();
       },
      load: function(){},   
      beforeunload: function() {
          $(window).scrollTop(0);
          // return nothing to stop 'default alert'
          return;
       } 

    }

$(document).on('ready', app.ready);
$(window).on('beforeunload', app.beforeunload);
```